# How to contcatenate multiple rows into a single row grouped by key column?

Tags: business-intelligence, informatica, informatica-powercenter, bi-tool

I have XML as source and target will be text file. I am pulling data from 2 tags in xml one is **Individual** and and other is **Professional designation** tag and **joining them based on Individual Internal Id key** column. We have Type column in professional designation tag **if we find more than one type for one Individual Internal ID** then for professional designation tag we need to pass more than one type into a single row separated with '|' symbol.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is an straight forward way to do it, but you can have an expression transformation after joiner and try to concatenate the "designation tag" if your current row's internal ID matches existing row.

As expression will process record by record, you can create variable and store the previous record value then compare it with new row.

Let me know if you need more info on implementation